# Remove all related children in Symfony entity

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

Suppose we have a field with ManyToMany relation as

```
/**
* @var ArrayCollection
* 
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Users")
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_roles",
*      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="User_Id", referencedColumnName="id")},
*      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="Role_Id", referencedColumnName="id")})
*/
protected $userRole;
```

To remove one related element from table we can have this function in our entity:

```
/**
* Remove userRole
* @param \Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Users $user
*/
public function remvoveUserRole(\Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Users $user)
{
    $this->userRole->removeElement($user);
}
```

**The Question**:

The `ArrayCollection` type has the function `removeElement` which is used to remove one element of the relationship. There is another function `clear` which in api says **Clears the collection, removing all elements**, therefore can I have a function like below in my entity to clear all the related elements so that by flushing it removes all?

```
/**
* Remove all user Roles
*/
public function remvoveAllUserRole()
{
    $this->userRole->clear();
}
```

will it work for just ManyToMany related tables or it might work for ManyToOne, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: **This logic works for ManyToMany relationship, but not for ManyToOne**

I tested the way to delete all related roles for specific use (ManyToMany) and it worked. What you need is to define a function in your UserEntity as

```
/**
* Remove all user Roles
*/
public function remvoveAllUserRole()
{
   $this->userRole->clear();
}
```

Then in your controller or anywhere else(if you need) you can call the function as below

```
$specificUser = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Users')->findOneBy(array('username' => 'test user'));
if (!empty($specificUser)) {
   $specificUser->removeAllUserRole();
   $em->flush();
}
```

Then it will delete all related roles for the *test user* and we don't need to use the for loop and remove them one by one

Answer (score 3):

`Ţîgan Ion` is right - `removeElement`/`clear` only removes those elements from memory.

However, I think you could achieve something as close depending on how did you configure `cascade` and `orphanRemoval` in your relationship.

```
$em = ...; // your EntityManager
$roles = $user->getRoles();
$roles->clear();
$user = $em->merge($user); // this is crucial
$em->flush();
```

In order for this to work, you need to configure `User` relationship to

- `cascade={"merge"}` - this will make `$em->merge()` call propagate to roles.
- `orphanRemoval = true` - since this is `@ManyToMany`, this will make `EntityManager` remove free-dangling roles.

Can't test this now, but as far as I can see it could work. I will try this out tomorrow and update the answer in need be.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tested and it seems working fine! This is how I did it: `$users = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Users')->findAll(); foreach ($users as $u) { $u->removeAllUserRole(); } $em->flush();` Then it removed all related roles for all users, without changing the mapping or other stuffs. However I don't know why it does not really catch me. :/

Answer (score -1):

if I'm not mistaken, this will not work, you have to delete the "role
s" from the arrayCollection directly from the database

```
$roles = $user->getRoles()
foreach $role from $roles 
           $em->remove($role);
$em->flush();
```

now you should get an empty collection

p.s: the best way is to test your ideas